# Problem with reporting Firebase custom event in Google Ads for iOS

Tags: ios, google-ads-api, firebase-analytics, idfa

Custom event from iOS app stream is reporting in Firebase correctly but doesn't work in Google Ads for iOS app campaigns. Of course, Firebase and Google Ads are connected. Moreover first_open and in_app_purchase tracking automatically by Firebase SDK in iOS are working correctly.

Comment: Could you clarify what do you mean by "doesn't work in Google Ads"? You can't import it or it's imported but conversions are not reported?

Comment: it's imported but conversions are not reported.

Comment: In some cases the reason is disable the AdSupport Framework: https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/analytics-adsupport